# How to create a new database in MongoDB using the c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have read through the mongodb documentation and cannot seem to find out how to create a new database. For example, in the documentation it says I can access the "test" database like this:

```
db.test.find()
```

Now what if I want to create my own database using syntax like this:

```
db.MyDB.find()
```

Also, is there any documentation I can read online I can further read about creating databases and collections using the DOS interface and the c# driver?

Comment: you don't need to create a database, just start using it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I may be wrong, but buried in [this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#CSharpDriverTutorial-Connectionstrings) it looks like the call to `GetDatabase` on the server object will actually create the database if it has not already been created.

So, the C# line:

```
server.GetDatabase("myDB");
```

Will create a new database named `myDB` the first time it is called.

---

From the documentation:

> **GetDatabase** maintains a table of MongoDatabase instances it has
>   returned before, so if you call **GetDatabase** again with the same
>   parameters you get the same instance back again.

Comment: If you actually want to find out whether a database exists or not (I know, that was not the OP's question here), you need to use `client.ListDatabaseNames` or `client.ListDatabaseNamesAsync` instead, and query it client-side.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific API/command required to create a DB in mongo. It creates it automatically when required. [Read this article.](http://theholmesoffice.com/how-to-create-a-mongodb-database/) to understand this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB driver has a feature where if a collection does not already exist then it automatically creates one. you can also use umongo an equivalent of Sql server management studio.
This video explains a clear sample to start off with 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x0-vHHHpv8